# Fedora Autologin in runlvel 3 and Autostart application

Tags: linux, fedora, boot

I have a single kernel with 2 menu entries in grub like following:

Boot(gfx) 
Boot(text)

First entry boot the fedora in graphical mode running the gnome.
Second entry boot the fedora in text mode.

First thing is working fine but i want to know how to do the second thing. i added 3 at the end of second entry in syslinux.cfg and after booting it dropped me at console asking for login.

So how to autologin in runlevel 3 and start autostart an application(e.g python script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is for Fedora 13, not test on other versions.

Open tty.conf in /etc/init/ and replace the following line

> exec /sbin/mingetty $TTY

with

> exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root
> --noclear $TTY

The above change will do an autologin for you.

Now change the .bash_profile file and add entries to autostart your application, for example:

> cd /MyApp
>
> python MyAppStart.py

The solution is tested and working well.

> Note: The above solution is not mine,
> a friend suggested it to me, So all
> credit goes to him. I am just posting
> here for the benefit of others.