# auto-execute user-interactive script when logining in runlevel 1 in fedora 16

Tags: linux, fedora, boot

I am looking to execute a user-interactive shell script once root logged in fedora 16. in another word, I need everything in my system to be automated ( auto root login and auto execute my shell) and end with my shell. how can i  execute a shell script on root login (CLI login NOT GUI) ?

note: i have seen this approach [Fedora Autologin in runlvel 3 and Autostart application](https://superuser.com/questions/160577/fedora-autologin-in-runlvel-3-and-autostart-application) but it does not work on FC16

solved by editing the /root/.bash_profile   :-)

Comment: solved by editing the /root/.bash_profile   :-)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer instead.